# What Does the A! Mean in XCODE 15 Source Control Navigator

Tags: version-control, xcode15

I am using "commit" for the first time in Xcode 15 and it is marking some files with a green A and a blue exclamation mark. Furthermore, the file (README) that has this indicator is marked as a deleted file. Why is it marking it "File Deleted"? I have more than one README file. I don't want the wrong one deleted. If I complete the commit, will the file be deleted?

See image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After experimentation, I found that the green A with the exclamation means "New file, but now missing". As for the deleted README file, I was able to figure out which README file was being deleted and which was being modified by simply adding small changes to the files and seeing how Xcode reacted. I sure there is a better way, but it worked. Finally, all this cleared up (no more green A's) when I clicked on Stage All followed by unstaging all of them. It seems to have compiled, so I guess no harm done